# Why is object axis broken in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes, axis, vector

I'm having an issue with Geometry Nodes where the object's Y and Z axes seem to be switched. The object should move along Z axis not Y. Orientation is set to global. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I found this for a fix maybe. https://usamababar.com/fixing-rotation-of-instances-of-geometry-nodes-in-blender/

Comment: Additional 180-degree rotation on z axis should fix problem after first post. go ahead edit me, but thanks for no help on the topic everyone!!!

Comment: lol...i don't want to...because of point 3. If you would have read my answer of geometry nodes you would have known that your question is super easy to answer....but i think you live in your own little world...and i won't answer you anymore because it is waste of time

Comment: I am being rude, sorry! You know your stuff. Read you profile, you have much to offer.

Comment: it's ok. I am glad you have self reflection.

Comment: lol sorry been at this for a day, gets upsetting.

Comment: I'm sorry for you if you have misunderstood the stack exchange platform but nobody is by any means obligated to provide anyone with any answers. We do this in our free time with our free will, we are not employees. If we know the answers, have the time, and are in a good mood, and feel that you are a nice person and deserve it then consider yourself blessed to get an answer. Apparently one of these conditions is not fulfilled as of the moment so you probably need more patience or we really don't know the answer :)

Comment: Some of us go to bed in a different time zone too! :^)

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize the direction of the axes about which each point will rotate by adding a few nodes to your group:

[image]

The points will rotate **about** axes in these (object-space) directions, but passing through the center, which you have asked to be the object origin.

[image]

Your calculated cross-product is a vector at right-angles to both `(0,0,0) -> Position` and `(0,0,-1)`.

In other words, normal to the triangle `(0,0,0) , Position , (0,0,-1)`.

In other other words, tangential to the sphere and lying in `XY`.

Comment: "Why the hot plate hot?" ...and Robin comes right along with a scientific paper as an answer! :D +1